# How to handle error of invoked_signed calls?

Tags: solana-program, invoke, error-handling

This is my sample code, I am trying to handle the error thrown from cross-invocation calls.

```
let result = invoke_signed(
      &instruction,
      &[re_account.clone()],
      &[&[b"reentrancy", &[address_bump]]],
            );
match result {
     Ok(()) => msg!("executed properly"),
     Err(err) => msg!("err {:?}", err.to_string()),
}
```

In case of valid instruction is showing the log "executed Properly".

But in case of invalid instruction, it is throwing error thus the whole transaction is reverting. Here I am expecting it to printing the err message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too complicated to properly return errors from child programs during CPI calls, so you can't actually handle the error from `invoke` or `invoke_signed`.  If a CPI errors, the whole transaction aborts immediately.

Comment: this sounds pretty problematic. I can imagine a number of scenarios where contingent logic needs to be executed if a user's transfer (i.e. CPI) fails.